# Как вычислить скорость загрузки файла через QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt

```
float timeToEnd = (bytesTotal - bytesReceived)/readBufferSize;
```

Попробовал так, но не получил адекватных значений

Comment: `QNetworkReply`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить переменную типа `QTime` и вызвать `QTime.start()`, когда начинается загрузка

Вычисления:

```
double speed = (bytesReceived * 1000.0)/currentTime.elapsed();
double timeToEnd = (bytesTotal - bytesReceived)/speed;
```